# stubborn urls.py - can't reload it under nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I know this has been already raised, but I still can't make it work. I've changed urls paths in the urls.py file. The changes are not being applied. Still the old version of the file is working.

I've tried reloading nginx server but it doesn't help. I run my django project under nginx with gunicorn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your setup (nginx + gunicorn + django?), I think that you need to restart gunicorn in order to reload the python/django application.

Comment: That helped me, thanks! To be more specific for next generations: get the pid from:$ ps aux. Then reload gunicorn: $ kill -HUP <PIP number>

Comment: Great! Instead of starting gunicorn manually, I would recommend you to use a process monitor (http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html#monitoring) such as supervisor (http://supervisord.org/).

Comment: it's already running under it. Which option should I choose to restart it, $ supervisorctl restart?

Comment: ok, you can restart a process supervised by using: `supervisorctl restart [name_of_process]`.